# Сущности в старом ядре Битрикса

Tags: php, база-данных, классы, битрикс, объекты

Читал [ORM](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=43&CHAPTER_ID=05748). В ней сказано, что

> *В старом ядре на каждую сущность программируется свой GetList, Update, Add, Delete.*

Что такое **сущности** в **старом ядре битрикса**?

Искал в интернете [bitrix getlist](https://www.google.com/search?q=bitrix%20GetList&oq=bitrix%20GetList&gs_lcrp=EgZjaHJvbWUyBggAEEUYOTIHCAEQABiABDIHCAIQABiABDIHCAMQABiABDIHCAQQABiABDIHCAUQABiABDIHCAYQABiABDIHCAcQABiABDIHCAgQABiABDIHCAkQABiABNIBCTEyMjU1ajBqN6gCALACAA&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#ip=1). Правильно ли я понял, что сущности в старом ядре битрикса - это экземпляры `CIBlockElement`, `CIBlockSection`, `CUser`, `CUserFieldEnum`, `CIBlockPropertyEnum`, `CGroup` и т.п.?

Прошу не минусовать - я новичок.